# Scraping excel from website using python with _doPostBack link url hidden

Tags: python, web-scraping, dopostback

For last few days I am trying to scrap the following website (link pasted below) which has a few excels and pdfs available in a table. I am able to do it for the home page successfully. There are total 59 pages from which these excels/ pdfs have to be scrapped. In most of the websites I have seen till now there is a query parameter which is available in the site url which changes as you move from one page to another. In this case, we have a _doPostBack function probably because of which the URL remains the same on every page you go to. I looked at multiple solutions and posts which are suggesting to see the parameters of `post` call and use them but I am not able to make sense of the parameters which are provided in `post` call (this is the first time I am scrapping a website).

Can someone please suggest some resource which can help me write a code which helps me  in moving from one page to another using python. The details are as follows:

Website link -  http://accord.fairfactories.org/ffcweb/Web/ManageSuppliers/InspectionReportsEnglish.aspx

My current code which extracts the CAP excel sheet from the home page (this is working perfect and is provided just for reference)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

Base = "http://accord.fairfactories.org/ffcweb/Web"
html = urlopen("http://accord.fairfactories.org/ffcweb/Web/ManageSuppliers/InspectionReportsEnglish.aspx")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
name = bs.findAll("td", {"class":"column_style_right column_style_left"})
i = 1
for link in bs.findAll("a", {"id":re.compile("CAP(?!\w)")}):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        name = str(i)+".xlsx"
        a = link.attrs['href']
        b = a.strip("..")
        c = Base+b
        urlretrieve(c, name)
        i = i+1
```

Please let me know if I have missed anything while providing the information and please don't rate me -ve else I won't be able to ask any questions further

Answer (score 0):

For aspx sites, you need to look for things like `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTVALIDATION` etc.. and post those parameters with each request, this will get all the pages and  using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) with *bs4*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin # python 3 use from urllib.parse import urljoin   



# All the keys need values set bar __EVENTTARGET, that stays the same.
data = {
    "__EVENTTARGET": "gvFlex",
    "__VIEWSTATE": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": "",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": ""}


def validate(soup, data):
    for k in data:
        # update post values in data.
        if k != "__EVENTTARGET":
            data[k] = soup.select_one("#{}".format(k))["value"]


def get_all_excel():
    base = "http://accord.fairfactories.org/ffcweb/Web"
    url = "http://accord.fairfactories.org/ffcweb/Web/ManageSuppliers/InspectionReportsEnglish.aspx"
    with requests.Session() as s:
        # Add a user agent for each subsequent request.
        s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"})
        r = s.get(url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        # get links from initial page.
        for xcl in bs.select("a[id*=CAP]"):
            yield urljoin(base, xcl["href"])
        # need to re-validate the post data in our dict for each request.
        validate(bs, data)
        last = bs.select_one("a[href*=Page$Last]")
        i = 2
        # keep going until the last page button is not visible
        while last:
            # Increase the counter to set the target to the next page
            data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = "Page${}".format(i)
            r = s.post(url, data=data)
            bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
            for xcl in bs.select("a[id*=CAP]"):
                yield urljoin(base, xcl["href"])
            last = bs.select_one("a[href*=Page$Last]")
            # again re-validate for next request
            validate(bs, data)
            i += 1


for x in (get_all_excel()):
    print(x)
```

If we run it on the first three pages, you can see we get the data you want:

```
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9965
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9552
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10650
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11969
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10086
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10905
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10840
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9229
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11310
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9178
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9614
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9734
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10063
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10871
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9468
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9799
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9278
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=12252
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9342
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9966
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11595
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9652
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10271
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10365
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10087
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9967
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11740
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=12375
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11643
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10952
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=12013
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9810
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10953
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10038
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9664
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=12256
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9262
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9210
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9968
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9811
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11610
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9455
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11899
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10273
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9766
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9969
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10088
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10366
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9393
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9813
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11795
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9814
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11273
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=12187
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10954
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9556
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11709
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9676
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10251
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10602
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10089
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9908
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10358
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9469
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11333
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9238
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9816
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9817
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10736
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10622
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9394
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9818
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=10592
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=9395
http://accord.fairfactories.org/Utilities/DownloadFile.aspx?id=11271
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Padraic. You are a star :)

Comment: Dear Padraic I am getting the following error when I am trying to execute the code. Can you please help again:

Comment: Error:      data[k] = soup.select_one("#{}".format(k))["value"]
               TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable